# Eclipse RCP EditorReference / IEditorPart

Tags: eclipse, editor, refresh, rcp

[Eclipse RCP components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUx6w.png)

I have small experience with Eclipse RCP and I'm wondering if some thinks are possible from the framework, or I should implement them.
Regarding to the attached image from the upper link I have some questions:
1. Is it possible to detect what EditorReference is Focused, Visible or Not Visible(I'm speaking for the Editors that are on >>4, opened but not visible)?

For me **FormData.java** EditorReference is **Visible** but **not Focused**, **FormLayout.java** is **Visible** and **Focused**, the other EditorReference behind **>>4** are **Not Visible**.

PS: I want to do this for an Eclipse RCP application that I write it now.

Comment: There are too many questions here. Please ask one specific question at a time.

Comment: I changed it but no answer, maybe there is not a valid solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link : https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_what_view_or_editor_is_selected%3F

```
IWorkbenchPage page = ...;
//the active part
IWorkbenchPart active = page.getActivePart();
//adding a listener
IPartListener2 pl = new IPartListener2() {
   public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPartReference ref)
      System.out.println("Active: "+ref.getTitle());
   }
   ... other listener methods ...
};
page.addPartListener(pl);
```